# Looking for a CiviCRM SAAS environment

Tags: hosting-providers

Are there any Civicrm SAAS providers? I don't want to maintain a CiviCRM installation, just be a user. I currently host a client's installation and no longer have capacity to maintain it. Would prefer to pay for someone else to maintain and just allow client to input data, edit data and send mailings.

Comment: Maybe SPARK may be the way to go for the limited needs this organization has, but would need someone to move the data over from CiviHosting to SPARK. Any suggestions on migration? We are willing to pay for the move.

Comment: Talk to @bgm on the spark channel at https://chat.civicrm.org

Comment: I think data migration is not supported by Spark, as it is intended to be just a hosted service with no paid custom support. There are many CiviCRM providers who offer hosting (https://civicrm.org/partners-contributors?custom_181=All&country_id=All&custom_157=Hosting&cms=All). Coop Symbiotic does a lot of bulk low cost hosting. My JMA Consulting are also getting into this.

Answer (score 3):

If your client's needs are fairly simple then [Spark](https://civicrm.com/) may suit them.

There is a listing of hosting providers [here](https://civicrm.org/partners-contributors?custom_181=All&country_id=All&custom_157=Hosting&cms=All) which represents a wide range of options:

- Some offer a hosting environment with CiviCRM installed and you manage the rest.
- Others provide a predefined set of extensions/configurations which may or may not suit.
- Others only provide hosting as part of a package of other services.
- Avoid anyone offering an 'enhanced' (lock-in) version.

You may need to contact a few to understand what is really on offer and what suits you.

Answer (score 1):

I have direct experience of just two, as a volunteer for a small charity, and only for a short time: [Spark](https://civicrm.com/) and [CiviHosting](https://civihosting.com/). They are distinct offerings: the former is more expensive but easier for a non-techie to cope with during the set-up phase, the latter is less expensive but harder for a non-techie to cope with during the set-up phase. The former imposes more constraints (e.g., in terms of selection of extensions), the latter imposes fewer constraints. I would heartily recommend both for their general helpfulness and speedy responses.